# Printing to HP LaserJet from Mac Issue

Tags: mac, printing, network-printer

I have a networked HP LJ 2100 that I can print from Windows with no problem.  When I try to send print jobs from my Macbook Pro (just purchased new) to it, the printer starts spitting out pages and pages of assembly code.

I set up the printer using "by IP", it is able to determine the type of printer correctly too.

Do I need to update my print drivers on the Mac or is there some sort of known issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like that is a known issue when printing from OS X.

Some folks on macosxhints.com seem to have come up with a fix using alternate Gutenprint drivers. http://forums.macosxhints.com/showthread.php?t=65101